# How to create a profile (for Event reg'n) from Form Processor or Afform?

Tags: profile

I need to create a profile with more options/actions (for example to create special relationships) than those provided by a classical profile and use it for event registration or contact creation.

I've looked up in Form Processor and Afform but couldn't find some advanced settings such as 'create profile' output.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you using Drupal as your CMS? If so maybe you could use webform and webform_civicrm to get the desired result?

Comment: In that case we use WP and external website using CiviMcRestFace connection.